# Replacing numbers in a text file in each iteration with random values

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, grep, random

I have a text file with the following content:

```
number of apples  7
```

I would like to run the shell script and modify the number with random values for say 5 iterations. So I need my output to look like this:

```
number of apples  7
number of apples  8
number of apples  1
number of apples  5
number of apples  4
```

I tried using the sed command as:

```
sed -i 's/Number of apples  7/Number of apples  '$((1 + RANDOM % 9))'/g' fruits.txt
```

In iteration 2, how do I automatically detect the new number and modify it?

Comment: wby do you need to detect the previous number when new number would be a random number?

Comment: Do the numbers need to be different for each of the 5 iterations?

Comment: Yes the new numbers have to be different. Detecting the new numbers is important for my problem as I need to generate the random number for the next step within a small range around the previous iteration value.

Comment: That statement in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/643362/replacing-numbers-in-a-text-file-in-each-iteration-with-random-values#comment1204670_643362) is by far the most important requirement you have (detecting numbers in strings is trivial and generating random numbers is trivial, but ensuring the new number is one unused in the previous iterations while also being random within the unused set is non-trivial) so please [edit] your question to state that. Also state what the range is for the random numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The regex for ranges is square brackets and a hyphen. So `[1-9]` will match anything from 1 to 9.

I.e. the `sed` code would change as follows:

```
's/Number of apples  [1-9]/Number of apples  '$((1 + RANDOM % 9))'/g'
```

Comment: this partially answer the question

Comment: With no context to link this to the question, this isn't an answer. It's only a vaguely relevant comment. Please try to only post answers that actually provide a full answer to the question.

Comment: Thank you Felix for your response. This does help.

Comment: @αғsнιη I cannot fully follow. In my understanding "detect" was rather targeting towards a general recognition of a single digit, i.e. using a regex.

Comment: @terdon Added where the `sed`-code needs to be updated. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @RitamChatterjee Does "does help" mean solve your problem or is this just a partially valid answer for your problem? If so, please explain what you are missing.

Comment: Now that  you have added the regex in my code, I'll be able to detect the numbers and modify accordingly in fixed ranges. So your solution is valid :)

Comment: It is indeed, thanks for the edit!